# Excel named range with relative reference is not calculating

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range called "cellabove" in my workbook that always references the cell above the cell it is used in. The RefersToR1C1 property of the name is "=!R[-1]C". This allows it to be applied on any worksheet in the workbook.

When I run a macro that deletes some rows then some cells containing cellabove in their formulas are not recalculating, even though I end the macro with application.calculatefullrebuild. However when I then manually force a full rebuild by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+F9 the cells do recalculate.

Any idea of how I can force the relative referenced named range to refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using refersto that start with ! in Defined Name formulas is IMHO not advisable as there are long-standing bugs.
You could use `=INDIRECT("R[-1]C",FALSE)` instead

Answer (score 1):

Try adding one of these calculation options into your code to see if they have an effect.

```
Sub Calculate_It()

    ActiveSheet.Calculate
''// Equivalent to Shift+F9 Recalculates the active worksheet

    Application.Calculate
''// Equivalent to F9 Recalculates all worksheets in all open workbooks

    Application.CalculateFull
''// Equivalent to Ctrl+Alt+F9 Recalculates all worksheets in all open workbooks (Full recalculation)

    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
''// Equivalent to Shift+Ctrl+Alt+F9 Rebuilds the dependency tree and does a full recalculation

End Sub
```

Comment: I've already said that I have application.calculatefullrebuild in my code. I have also tried all the other options.

Comment: @aardvark123 It may then be helpful to see the code you're running.